# How do I associate python with a particular file in windows?

Tags: python, windows

I am trying to run the following, but powershell won't recognize it. How would I run the following in windows?

```
assoc .py=Python.File
ftype Python.File="C:\Users\Username\workspace\demo\env\Script\python.exe" "%1" %*
```

Comment: question is still not django related...

Comment: It is so I can get django to work, that is one of the things they require.

Comment: Well you need it for django, but the question itself is totally unrelated to django.

Comment: `assoc` and `ftype` are built-in commands of the cmd.exe shell.

Comment: These commands change the system settings in `HKLM\Software\Classes`, but you could have a per-user setting in `HKCU\Software\Classes` or Explorer's selected association that takes precedence, so it isn't always enough to run `assoc` and `ftype`. You may also have to use Explorer's open-with dialog to select the system Python file type.

Comment: When I run assoc .py=Python.File in cmd.exe, I get "Access is denied. Error occurred while processing .py"

Comment: It modifies `HKLM\Software\Classes`, which is only accessible by administrators. You need to run cmd with elevated access.

Comment: Ok I got it, thanks.